# c# forms blocking other control when show dialog called

Tags: c#, forms

When my application is loading. I display a progress bar using the code below. The problem is if someone clicks on the toolbar context menu (the way to exit) it will be blocked until this the progress bar is closed. Does anyone know a better way of achieving this?

The reason I'm using `ShowDialog` is that when I used `Show` the progress bar wouldn't animate - I'm using the MarqueeStyle.

Thanks

```
public partial class PopUpProgessBar : Form
{
    public PopUpProgessBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Thread t;
    private void StartAnmiation()
    {
        this.Update();
        this.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (t != null)
        { 
            t.Abort();
            t.Join();
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (t == null)
        {
            t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.StartAnmiation));
            t.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It isn't blocked until the progress bar stops, it is blocked until your app finishes loading and starts being responsive to commands.  Pretty inevitable.  Takes a while for F5 to work in VS as well.  This kind of code is very dangerous, make sure your app doesn't deadlock when you press the Windows + L key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code doesn't look quite right. Are you sure it doesn't throw cross-thread violations? In general, your whole metaphor here is wrong. You need to keep the GUI on the GUI thread. Load your application on the background thread and have it send progress updates to the GUI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your PopupProgressBar form shouldn't be responsible for loading itself in a new thread, that should be done in presumably your main window.

I would get rid of all the thread stuff in PopupProgressBar and make it simply start updating it's marquee.  Then, in your main window (OnLoad) you tell it to do it's thing:

```
        bool done = false;
        PopupProgressBar splashForm = null;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x) =>
        {
            using (splashForm = new PopupProgressBar ())
            {
                splashForm.Show();
                while (!done)
                    Application.DoEvents();
                splashForm.Close();
            }
        });

        // do all your initialization work here
        // also, during each step of your initialization you could send call a function
        // in splashForm to update

        done = true;
```